# Are these cracks in our wall something to be concerned about?

Tags: drywall, walls, foundation, crack, cracks

There are a couple of cracks that have been in our wall for about 5-6 years.  They haven’t gotten any worse, and I don’t see any other cracks anywhere else in our home.  I was going to fill them in and paint over them, but I just want to make sure that they aren’t anything serious.

[image]

Comment: Could just be settlement cracks.  I'd fill them with joint compound (or something else that's non-stretching.  If you see cracks again in a few years, then you may have a problem.  If no cracks, you're either continuing to settle, or have a bigger problem.

Comment: Great- thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up that response.  I meant to say, if you have cracks in a few years, you may be continuing to settle, or have a bigger problem.  If no cracks, you've probably stopped settling and should be fine.

Comment: How old is the house? How long have you lived there relative to that? Is this decoration you did or has it not been decorated since you moved there... so you have a time-scale for these cracks relative to the last two numbers? [Late point… are you sure it's drywall? I've never lived anywhere with that on walls, but on ceilings it tends to go at the edges of each piece, not ragged lines in the middle]

Comment: I have live here for 21 years.  The crack has been here for at least 8-10 years.  It has not been decorated since I've been here.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You may have a point. My place is plaster-over-lsth, and definitely had some diagonal cracks due to settling. (At this point it _should_ be stabilized, but some stressed ro occasionally work their way thru to the surface. After 120+ years there's no such thing as plumb or level, and that's ok.)

Answer (score 1):

I would get a 1" putty knife and fill in that crack with joint compound. Have a damp sponge ready and clean off the excess mud from the area outside of the crack so you don't ruin the wall texture. If there is an orange peel texture, dab the area with the sponge. When done, that crack will be almost unnoticeable so you won't need to immediately paint the room.

Comment: Thanks- I will do that.